# How can i detect video duration from url?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I use better_player package i need to detect the video duration data from the url only
i used to uploude the video from dashboard and retrive it in application i need to detect the duration and extract it as a variable

can any one help me in this problem

I searched for any way to detect it and i found nothing

Comment: About what URL are you talking about? A download URL from Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 0):

there is one way to get the duration of video from videoPlayerController[1](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player):

```
VideoPlayerController _controller = _betterPlayerController.videoPlayerController;
```

Once your get the controller:

```
Duration _duration = _controller.value.duration;
```